Border of riemann surface given by quotient of fuchsian group
Let $\Gamma \subset PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ be discrete, and consider the Riemann surface $\mathbb{H} / \Gamma$ with the unique complex structure for which the quotient map $\pi : \mathbb{H} \rightarrow \mathbb{H} / \Gamma$ is holomorphic.
Assume that the set of accumulation points of any orbit of $\Gamma$ ,$L$, is not all of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$, and take some $z_0 \in \overline{\mathbb{R}} \setminus L$.
Then there is some open interval containing $z_0$ entirely contained in the complement of $L$, and it is apparently the case that this open interval corresponds to a boundary arc on the border of the Riemann surface $\mathbb{H} / \Gamma$, i.e. one can adjoin this boundary arc to the Riemann surface and consider $\mathbb{H} / \Gamma \subset \mathbb{H} \cup (\overline{\mathbb{R}} \setminus L) / \Gamma$ where the latter is given the quotient topology.
Then it seems to me that we would also have that there is some $\epsilon > 0$, for which on the half-disk of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $z_0$, $\pi \restriction \Delta(z_0,\epsilon) \cap \overline{\mathbb{H}}$ is injective, so that in this half disk, no two points are in the same orbit.
I can see that it is impossible for $\Gamma(x)$ to accumulate at $z_0$, for any $x$, but I do not know how to go from this to concluding the existence of such a half disk.

The key words here are that $\Gamma$ is a Fuchsian group, $L$ is the limit set of $\Gamma$, and $\Omega=\overline{\mathbb R} - L$ is the domain of discontinuity of $\Gamma$. The key result is that the restricted action of $\Gamma$ on $\mathbb H \cup \Omega$ is free and properly discontinuous. Of course, so far this is just re-expressing your question with words and terminologies. But you can look up these key words, and find proofs for your questions, in many textbooks on Fuchsian groups.

@LeeMosher Thanks, just to clarify - the action would be free on $\Omega$ but not necessarily on the upper half plane unless we specify $\Gamma$ acts without fixed points? But always it will be free on $\Omega$?

Ah, good point, I failed to take into account that you did not specify freeness of the action on $\mathbb H$. In brief, one needs another concept: the convex hull of the limit set; and one needs to verify that the fixed points of the finite order elements are contained in the convex hull. That implies the action is free on a neighborhood of each point of $\Omega$ in $\mathbb H \cup \Omega$. I'll write up a full answer soon.
